# Bootstrap pkgsrc on macosx (10.9) error

Tags: macos, sed

I am trying to bootstrap pkgsrc-2014Q2 on OS X 10.9.

The script complains:

```
cd /Users/tiramo/Downloads/pkgsrc-2014Q2/bootstrap/work/wrk/pkgtools/bootstrap-mk-files/work/bootstrap-mk-files-20140516; for file in bsd.* sys.mk; do           test ! -f mods/Darwin.$file ||          /bin/cp -f mods/Darwin.$file /Users/tiramo/Downloads/pkgsrc-2014Q2/bootstrap/work/wrk/pkgtools/bootstrap-mk-files/work/bootstrap-mk-files-20140516/$file;       done
cd /Users/tiramo/Downloads/pkgsrc-2014Q2/bootstrap/work/wrk/pkgtools/bootstrap-mk-files/work/bootstrap-mk-files-20140516;                            if test -f mods/Darwin.bsd.own.mk.in; then          own_mk=mods/Darwin.bsd.own.mk.in;           else                                own_mk=mods/bsd.own.mk.in;              fi;                                 /Users/tiramo/Downloads/pkgsrc-2014Q2/bootstrap/work/bin/sed   -e 's|@ROOT_GROUP@|'wheel'|g'            -e 's|@ROOT_USER@|'root'|g'             -e 's|@SYSCONFDIR@|'/usr/pkg/etc'|g'        $own_mk > bsd.own.mk
===> Installing for bootstrap-mk-files-20140516
ERROR: bootstrap-mk-files-20140516 is already installed - perhaps an older version?
ERROR: If so, you may use either of:
ERROR:     - "pkg_delete bootstrap-mk-files-20140516" and "/Users/tiramo/Downloads/pkgsrc-2014Q2/bootstrap/work/bin/bmake reinstall"
ERROR:       to upgrade properly
ERROR:     - "/Users/tiramo/Downloads/pkgsrc-2014Q2/bootstrap/work/bin/bmake update" to rebuild the package and all
ERROR:       of its dependencies
ERROR:     - "/Users/tiramo/Downloads/pkgsrc-2014Q2/bootstrap/work/bin/bmake replace" to replace only the package without
ERROR:       re-linking dependencies, risking various problems.
*** Error code 1
```

But I don't have any previous version! I removed everying under `/usr/pkg`. Where is the script looking for the exsiting install? How can I get around it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around the problem by erasing the file list of the correspondig package:

```
rm -rf /var/db/pkg/bootstrap-mk-files*
```

[Solution found evetually here](https://mail-index.netbsd.org/pkgsrc-users/2010/02/04/msg011647.html).